# clang++ as drop-in g++ replacement

Tags: clang++

I'm trying to use `clang++` as drop-in replacement for G++. I'm compiling for AArch64, but for linking, `clang` seems to invoke the native (x86) `/usr/bin/ld` instead of that from AArch64 GCC suite. The `clang` command line looks like:

```
clang++ -target aarch64-linux-gnu -v \
  -gcc-toolchain /path/to/aarch64/gcc \
  --sysroot=/path/to/aarch64/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc \
  <some other options> <obj files>
```

And from the verbose output, I get:

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: aarch64--linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /path/to/aarch64/gcc/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Selected GCC installation: /path/to/aarch64/gcc/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
 "/usr/bin/ld" --sysroot=/path/to/aarch64/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc ...
```

I don't get why `clang` got around choosing the native linker. The link fails for obvious reasons that object files are AArch64 ELF. Compilation lines similar to the above, but they go OK.

Any thoughts?

PS: I'm a novice `clang` user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution: GCC accepts `-B` option to point to the search path where it'd try to locate the utilities. It turns out--although not documented--that clang too accepts this option. For me, having `-B` point to AArch64 binutils solved the problem. Another suggestion was to add the AArch64 binutils in `$PATH`.